# How to find index that has same value in another array by python?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I'm a beginner of Python. I would like to find indexes that have two largest values in ndarray. For example, ndarray x like this.

```
x = np.array([2,3,5,3,7,3,1,5])
```

Because the two largest values are 7 and 5. The answer should be

```
ind = [2,4,7]
x[ind] = [5,7,5]
```

Would you tell me how to code it?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in 3 steps:

1. Sort your unique array values (np.unique also sorts) `np.unique(…)`
2. Slice the last N values (the maximums) from the sorted unique array `…[-max_n:]`
3. Find the indices where your array has those maximums via `np.where(np.isin(…))`

```py
import numpy as np

max_n = 2
x = np.array([2,3,5,3,7,3,1,5])
max_values = np.unique(x)[-max_n:]
max_indices = np.where(np.isin(x, max_values))[0]

print(
    f'{max_indices    = }',
    f'{x[max_indices] = }',
    sep='\n'
)
largest_indices    = array([2, 4, 7])
x[largest_indices] = array([5, 7, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) selector. First you extract indices of the maximum value, then you work identically on a subset of the original array without this last value(s)

```
x = np.array([2,3,5,3,7,3,1,5])
largest_indices = np.where(x == np.max(x))[0]
# In one line you select the subarray without the largest value
largest2_indices = np.where(x == np.max(x[x < np.max(x)]))[0]
ind = np.sort(np.concatenate((largest_indices, largest2_indices)))
```

Or, in one single, confusing, line:

```
ind = np.sort(np.where((x == np.max(x)) | (x == np.max(x[x < np.max(x)])))[0])
```

The result:

```
print(ind)
>>> [2 4 7]
print(x[ind])
>>> [5 7 5]
```

Answer (score -1):

Theres several ways to accomplish this. One simple way is to

1. Sort the array

```
_sorted=np.argsort(x)
```

2.select the largest 2 values

```
_max=x[-1]
second=_sorted[np.searchsorted(_sorted,_max)]
```

3. Find the indexs with those values

```
  ind=np.where(x==max or x==second)
```

**Updated with suggestions from Buzz

Comment: Using `for` cycle for numpy array is highly discouraged. Numpy is a wrapper of a C/C++ library with performance in mind. *looping* an array in Python would disrupt this goal.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Why return is there?

Comment: Moreover, better using `_max` as variable, so as not to shadow built-in function `max`. The same for `_sorted` instead of `sorted`

Comment: Improved the current answer with a numpy function. Also removed the return to be more inline with your original problem.